# rosusarsim pioneer laser sensore read error

Tags: laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to read data sensor of pioneer robot which i call in usarsim using ros indigo and try this code
ican move the robot using teleope key board backage but iwant to read data

> ~$ rostopic list  /rosout /rosout_agg
> > ksam@ksam-K53SC:~$ rostopic echo
> /base_scan WARNING: topic [/base_scan]
> does not appear to be published yet
> ^Cksam@ksam-K53SC:~$

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199652/rosusarsim-pioneer-laser-sensore-read-error/) by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, first make sure your P3AT is spawned in USARSim, and then you can see the laser data on `/lms topic` through `rostopic echo /lms`.

usarsim_inf that is used to connect ros-usarsim does not publish the laser data on `/base_scan topic`

---

Originally posted by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) with karma: 351 on 2014-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0